# Beamer add title graphic to the top

Tags: beamer, floats, titles, presentations

**What I want**

I would like to align my title grafic to the top center.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

%no navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%no headline
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
%no footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
%insert frame numbering
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{
    \usebeamerfont{footline}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}
    \hspace{1em}
    \large \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
%no frame number on the title frame
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begingroup
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
  \endgroup
}
%title frame does not count towards the numbering
\let\otp\titlepage
\renewcommand{\titlepage}{\otp\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}


%black title color
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
%black frame title color
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}



\titlegraphic{
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logopolito}
    \hspace*{1cm}~%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logopolito}
    \hspace*{1cm}~%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logopolito}
}
\author{Author\\[10mm]{\small Supervisor: Supervisor}}
\title{Title}
\institute{Institute}
\date{Date}



\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\frame[plain]{\titlepage}
\endgroup


\begin{frame}{Test 1}

\begin{columns}

\column{0.5\textwidth}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
\column{0.5\textwidth}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
\end{columns}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Test 2}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Screenshots**

Currently how it looks like.

[image]

How should looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `\titlegraphic` macro, you could place your images at the start of the frame which holds your titlepage:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

%no navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%no headline
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
%no footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
%insert frame numbering
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{
    \usebeamerfont{footline}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}
    \hspace{1em}
    \large \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
%no frame number on the title frame
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begingroup
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
  \endgroup
}
%title frame does not count towards the numbering
\let\otp\titlepage
\renewcommand{\titlepage}{\otp\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}


%black title color
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
%black frame title color
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}



\author{Author\\[10mm]{\small Supervisor: Supervisor}}
\title{Title}
\institute{Institute}
\date{Date}



\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\frame[plain]{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logopolito}
    \hspace*{1cm}~%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logopolito}
    \hspace*{1cm}~%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logopolito}

\titlepage}
\endgroup


\begin{frame}{Test 1}

\begin{columns}

\column{0.5\textwidth}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
\column{0.5\textwidth}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
\end{columns}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Test 2}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So bacis and how clever, thanks

Comment: @pal99 You're welcome! Have fun with beamer!